# SQL Plus change current directory

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

How does one change the current directory in SQL Plus under windows.

I am trying to write a script with several  "@ filename" commands.

I know that one can open a script with the File --> Open command, which will change the current directory, but I am looking for a way to do this automatically unattended.

---

### Resolution

Based on Plasmer's response, I set the SQLPATH environment variable in Windows, and got something that's good enough for me. I did not try to set it with the HOST command (I doubt that it will work).

Pourquoi Litytestdata's answer is a good one, but will not work for me (the directories are too far apart). And of course Guy's answer that it cannot be done is also correct. I will vote these two up, and accept Plasmer's answer.

Comment: For all those coming across this pay particular attention to Tom's answer. It is most likely the issue. You have to use the "cd" command in windows BEFORE running the 'sqlplus' command. The cd should change the directory to the one which contains the script to run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could you use the SQLPATH environment variable to tell sqlplus where to look for the scripts you are trying to run?  I believe you could use HOST to set SQLPATH in the script too.

There could potentially be problems if two scripts have the same name and both directories are in the SQLPATH.

Answer (score 21):

Here is what I do.

Define a variable to help you out:

```
define dir=C:\MySYSTEM\PTR190\Tests\Test1

@&dir\myTest1.sql
```

You can't `cd` in SQL*Plus (you can `cd` using the host command, but since it is a child process, the setting won't persist in your parent process).

Comment: Nice easy solution.  Minor update though...  You need an "=" between "dir" and "C:\..."

Answer (score 11):

I don't think that you can change the directory in SQL*Plus.

Instead of changing directory, you can use `@@filename`, which reads in another script whose location is relative to the directory the current script is running in.  For example, if you have two scripts

```
C:\Foo\Bar\script1.sql
C:\Foo\Bar\Baz\script2.sql
```

then `script1.sql` can run `script2.sql` if it contains the line

```
@@Baz\script2.sql
```

See [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_.40_and_.40.40.3F) for more info about `@@`.

Comment: @@ only works for me when script2 is in the same directory as script1. The text you've linked also says "@@ will start a sqlplus script that is in the same directory as the script that called it". Does the example you've given really work for you?

Comment: @Karl: does @@ work if you use forward slashes instead of backslashes?

Comment: -1 because it only works in the special case that sqlplus has been started from C:\Foo\Bar. Start from any other directory and the command will fail with a "SP2-0310: unable to open file"

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can!

```
/home/export/user1 $ sqlplus / 
> @script1.sql
> HOST CD /home/export/user2
> @script2.sql
```

script2.sql has to be in `/home/export/user1`.

You either use the full path, or exit the script and start `sqlplus` again from the right directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
oraenv .
cd /home/export/user1
sqlplus / @script1.sql
cd /home/export/user2
sqlplus / @script2.sql
```

(something like that - doing this from memory!)

Comment: _script2.sql has to be in /home/export/user_:  Do you mean _/home/export/user1_ (a typo?)?

Comment: @HansDeragon - Blimey, a (nearly) 10 year old typo!

Comment: start sqlplus from the right directory.  what a concept ! :)

Answer (score 3):

With Oracle's new SQLcl there is a cd command now and accompanying pwd.
SQLcl can be downloaded here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html

Here's a quick example:

```
SQL>pwd
/Users/klrice/
NOT_SAFE>!ls *.sql
db_awr.sql  emp.sql     img.sql     jeff.sql    orclcode.sql    test.sql
db_info.sql fn.sql      iot.sql     login.sql   rmoug.sql

SQL>cd sql
SQL>!ls *.sql
003.sql             demo_worksheet_name.sql     poll_so_stats.sql
1.sql               dual.sql            print_updates.sql

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating a windows shortcut for sql plus and set the working directory?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the SQLPATH environment variable is the best way for this - if you have multiple paths, enter them separated by semi-colons (;). Keep in mind that if there are script files named the same in among the directories, the first one encountered (by order the paths are entered) will be executed, the second one will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Years later i had the same problem. My solution is the creation of a temporary batchfile and another instance of sqlplus:

In first SQL-Script:

```
:
set echo off
spool sqlsub_tmp.bat
prompt cd /D D:\some\dir
prompt sqlplus user/passwd@tnsname @second_script.sql
spool off
host sqlsub_tmp.bat
host del sqlsub_tmp.bat
:
```

Note that "second_script.sql" needs an "exit" statement at end if you want to return to the first one..

Comment: I use `echo exit | sqlplus ...` quite a lot.

Answer (score -2):

for me shelling-out does the job because it gives you possibility to run [a|any] command on the shell:

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_display_current_directory_sqlplus.htm

in short see the current directory:

`!pwd`

change it

`!cd /path/you/want`

Comment: As Tom already stated above, and Guy confirmed by experiment, that doesn't work.  Your "any" command is run in the shell child process, and affects that, but not sql*plus.